# No message en formulario

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla User, la cual entre sus variables tiene una llamada saldo, que es de tipo entero y es para indicar cuanto dinero tiene un usuario.
Quiero hacer un formulario el cual escriba un número el usuario. Si el saldo del usuario es nulo (o es igual a 0), este número se pondra como saldo, pero si ya tenia un saldo, se sumara a su cantidad actual.

Formulario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

@Logged()
@include('partials.errors')
<form method="POST" action="../saldo">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="saldo" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Saldo actual") }}
                </label>
                <input id="saldo" class="form-control" name="saldo" value="{{ old('saldo') }}"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="addSaldo" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Ingresar saldo") }}
            </button>
        </form>
@else
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute" style="color:#FF0000"> {{ __("¡DEJA DE HACER EL INDIO Y INICIA SESIÓN!") }} </h1>
@endLogged
@endsection
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/saldo','UserController@store');
```

Y en método en UserController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $normas=[
            'saldo' => 'required',
        ];

        $this->validate($request,$normas);

        if(empty(Auth::user()->saldo))
            Auth::user()->saldo=$request->$saldo;
        else    
            Auth::user()->saldo+=$request->$saldo;
        Auth::user()->save();
        return back()->with('message', ['success', __("Su ingreso se ha efectuado con exito.")]);
    }
```

Pero ejecuto el formulario y me topo con esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si pongo en la primera linea de store() algo como dd("Listo") tambien me sale el mensaje de error. Funciona si accedo directamente en vez de a traves del formulario, por lo que imagino que el error esta en el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás enviando un formulario con post a una ruta get, el mensaje de error es "método no permitido".

Define entonces la ruta con post:

```
Route::post('saldo', 'UserController@store');
```

Comment: Pues gracias, ahora ya he conseguido que se realice el ingreso.